# What is best control in Java for simple editor

Tags: java, javax.swing.text

I need to implement light editor ( recognize part of key words, syntax highlight and suggest all of word in dropdown list if user type part with same prefix). What is best control in Java for this task ?

Comment: What criteria are you judging "best" by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the [Java Tutorial - Using Text Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) along with the [examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TextSamplerDemo) page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`JEditTextArea`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/textarea/textarea/2.2.3/textarea-2.2.3.jar!/net/sf/textarea/JEditTextArea.class?classDetails=ok) as a start point.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to reuse the editor of NetBeans or Eclipse.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/How_to_create_support_for_a_new_language

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html